# R - Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Column `center` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2

Tags: r, dplyr, r-car

I'm trying to calculate the center of each group, by running the `calc_center` function with `dplyr`'s `group_by_` and `summarise` functions. However, I received an error saying that the column must be 1 column not two. What can I do to bypass it? This is my code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(car)

calc_center <- function(x,y){
  MASS::cov.trob(cbind(x, y)$center
}

results <- data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(center=calc_center(Latitude, Longitude))
```

This is my error

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :
```

Column `center` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2

Answer (score 3):

In the future, it'd be nice if you included at least a brief example of your data for troubleshooting/reproducibility purposes.

The issue is likely because you'd like to apply the function to each row for the `Latitude` and `Longitude` columns. 
In this case, using `dplyr::rowwise()` should solve the issue:

E.g.;

```
results <- data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  summarise(center=calc_center(Latitude, Longitude)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

You could also probably get away with using `mutate` instead of `summarise`.

Hope that was helpful!

Comment: This was super helpful to me. It took me an embarrassingly long time to see that I was trying to pass the whole df to the function inside `summarize`, and not just 1 column. I decided to use `map_dfr` on unique values of one variable, sort of like this: `map_dfr(unique(my.df$mycol), function(x){newval<-my.df %>% filter(mycol==x) %>% myfun return(newval, x})`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your function `calc_center`, the `y` in `cov.trob` is getting assigned to `wt`

In `?MASS::cov.trob`

```
cov.trob(x, wt = rep(1, n), cor = FALSE, center = TRUE, nu = 5,
     maxit = 25, tol = 0.01)
```

You will see that `x` is of type matrix, this will hold your *latitude* and *longitude*